# Hashicorp Vault Policy is not getting assigned

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to assign a policy to my ldap group/user so that a user can access the auth methods but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my situation.

I have a policy name - `test-ldap-group` with capabilities :

```
path "auth/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}

path "kv/*" {
  capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]
}
```

Now I have assigned this policy to my ldap group : `test-group`. The 2nd one with `"kv/*` is working fine because I can see the secrets on deployed on kv engine but the 1st one where I am trying to assign the auth method it just gives me the error -

```
Not authorized
Ember Data Request GET /v1/identity/entity/id?list=true returned a 403 Payload (application/json) [object Object]

1 error occurred: * permission denied
```

Also this works - (this gives access to everything under `kv/` which we don't want)

```
path "kv/*" {
  capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]
}
```

BUT this doesn't work

```
path "kv/staging/db" {
  capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]
}
```

What could be i am doing wrong here?

**Vault Version - Vault v1.5.3**

**kv version - 1**

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint that is failing for you is [this endpoint](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/identity/entity#list-entities-by-id) for listing identities. It may be the case that when you are calling this command, your user or `VAULT_TOKEN` don't have the required permissions to list entities. You can try to log into Vault as the `root` user or use the root `VAULT_TOKEN` if you are executing the commands via cURL, for example.